# Table and Array

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have problem with TableView its empty.

In (.h) file:

```
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController{

NSMutableArray *coursArray; }
```

In (.m) file:

In `viewDidLoad`

```
[coursArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"AR111",@"courseCode",@"Arabic Communication Skills (I)",@"courseName", nil]];
[coursArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"AR112",@"courseCode",@"Arabic Communication Skills (II)",@"courseName", nil]];
```

and in `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
return [coursArray count];
```

and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[coursArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"courseCode"];
```

So whats wrong please help me :)

Comment: are you sure that you set the delegate and the dataSource of the table correctly?

Comment: Omar makes a great suggestion. You could put NSLog or debugger breakpoints at numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath and make sure they're being invoked like you think they should.

Comment: And, of course, I assume you're doing the necessary `alloc` and `init` of coursArray itself (e.g. `coursArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`), too, in viewDidLoad, too, because you're not showing that here.

Comment: Yes, if I use cell.textLabel.text = @"Yes"; with numberOfRowsInSection return 2; its work.

Comment: thanks its work now I forgot coursArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]

Comment: As an aside, if the individual objects in coursArray aren't changing, you could make them plain ol' NSDictionary's rather than NSMutableDictionary's. Completely unrelated to your original question, but just an observation. The array is mutable, but it doesn't mean that the individual objects need to be mutable, too. (Obviously, if you're going to change those dictionary items later, then clearly make them mutable if you want, but not needed on the basis of the code shown thus far.)

Comment: thanks Robert Ryan its the [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; it work now ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good. Just make sure to do the necessary alloc and init of coursArray itself in viewDidLoad, too, e.g.

```
coursArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
```